# How should I pass a value from a JFrame to another?

Tags: java, jframe

I have this logical problem regarding on how to pass value from one JFrame to another.

What I want to do:

Since all value inputted by the user were automatically saved into a database, I want to capture first the ID and then pass it on to another JFrame were it will show the recently stored data.

So, basically I have a **JFrame** were the user will fill up all the required information, after hitting the submit button, I want to show **another JFrame** showing that the addition of an Item were successful while showing the previous data inputted.

Problem:

I don't know how to pass the value I have got(using a database query) from the first JFrame to another JFrame(where the user will see the complete information recently stored).

here's a sample code:

```
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT cId, LastName, FirstName, "
                + "Address, TelNo, Email from pcontacts WHERE FirstName ='"
                +firstname.getText()+"' AND LastName ='"+lastname.getText()+"'");

        int cId;
        String LastName, FirstName, Address, TelNo, Email;
        if(counter == 0){
            if(rs.next()) {
                //cId = rs.getInt("cId");
                LastName = rs.getString("LastName");
                FirstName = rs.getString("FirstName");
                Address = rs.getString("Address");
                TelNo = rs.getString("TelNo");
                Email = rs.getString("Email");

                fname.setText(FirstName);
                lname.setText(LastName);
                address.setText(Address);
                contact.setText(TelNo);
                email.setText(Email);
                counter++;
```

**How can i pass the cId to another JFrame?**

Please Help. Thanks in Advance :)

PS

hope you understand my explanation.. if you have any other questions regarding my explanation.. please do tell me, I will try my best to explain it further. Thanks again

Comment: How about passing that value in constructor of second frame? Is it possible in your case?

Comment: Or adding a public int getId() that returns the value...

Comment: like the "Getter and Setter"? I've tried it awhile ago but i can't pass the value to another JFrame successfully.  :(

Comment: Very few applications need more than one frame.  Consider using a `JDialog` or `JOptionPane` for secondary floating GUI elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prefered way in many cases is to use PropertyChangeListeners, look at tutorial at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom class extending JFrame, with a private member in it, and initialize it in the constructor.